# select query for getting data from two table

Tags: c#, sql

I would like to know the following:

Location- Table name

Locationid int primary key
LocationName varchar

location table data (23,kochi),(24,trivandrum)

flight - table name

```
sourceid foreign key : value 23
destination id forien key : value 24
```

now i need to show the Locationname as SourceName and destinationName and show these two records pls help me

i need to show like this

```
SourceName   DestinationName 

Kochi        Trivandrum
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to join to the Location table twice:

```
SELECT 
    s.LocationName SourceName,
    d.LocationName DestinationName
FROM flight f
    INNER JOIN Location s on f.sourceid - s.LocationID
    INNER JOIN Location d on f.destinationid - d.LocationID
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.D Stanley It is Successful